# Sign a module after kernel compilation

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, security, signature

I've built a kernel in tmpfs, then I rebooted.

Now I see a message when I compile the 3rd party module,

`NO SIGN [M] XXXX.ko`

How can I get it signed? The key pair generated during `rpmbuild` is lost already I guess

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was surprisingly lacking in documentation. I found this file, [module-signing.txt](https://github.com/bergwolf/rhel6/blob/master/Documentation/module-signing.txt), which is part of the RHEL6 Kernel Documentation. In this document it shows how to generate signing keys, assuming you want to sign all your modules as part of a kernel build:

```
cat >genkey <<EOF
%pubring kernel.pub
%secring kernel.sec
Key-Type: DSA
Key-Length: 512
Name-Real: A. N. Other
Name-Comment: Kernel Module GPG key
%commit
EOF
make scripts/bin2c
gpg --homedir . --batch --gen-key genkey
gpg --homedir . --export --keyring kernel.pub keyname |
 scripts/bin2c ksign_def_public_key __initdata >crypto/signature/key.h
```

Also the article from Linux Journal titled: [Signed Kernel Modules](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7130) has some good details and steps on how to do pieces of this, but I couldn't find the user space tools, `extract_pkey` and `mod` that it references.

You might want to poke around [Greg Kroah's site](http://www.kroah.com/linux/), you may find something useful in one of his presentations.

#### References

- [Signed Kernel Modules - linux journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7130)
- [Howto Use Signed Kernel Modules](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/signed-kernel-modules-1891111.html)

Comment: Do I need to configure the system to trust the cert?

Comment: @warl0ck - all I know about signing them was added to this answer. I'd never even contemplated signing them until you asked this Q.

Comment: I found this link very useful. https://github.com/Canonical-kernel/Ubuntu-kernel/blob/master/Documentation/module-signing.txt Looks like there's no way to install a module to a prebuilt kernel, if it's signed by a 3rdparty ..

Answer (score 1):

Go to the kernel source directory and do (example):

```
./scripts/sign-file sha512 ./signing_key.priv ./signing_key.x509 /lib/modules/3.10.1/kernel/drivers/char/my_module.ko
```

Check what is the digest algorithm your kernel is using by opening .config and reading it  in `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG` config values:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA512=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_HASH="sha512"
```