# Signing a module for prebuilt kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, security, kernel-modules, certificates

I am developing linux driver for my own PCI device. 
I am stuck on starting my module:

```
[14941.205599] mymod321: module verification failed: signature and/or
required key missing - tainting kernel
```

I have read this [how to](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Signed_kernel_module_support) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74022/sign-a-module-after-kernel-compilation).
But it is useful when build own kernel.

I use Ubuntu 14.4.2 LTE on my PC.

Is there any way to get key pair (*.priv + *.509) from current prebuilt kernel to sign my kernel module?
Or do I have to recompile the Ubuntu kernel for a new key?

Comment: Hi Jeff, Any lucky to this question?